# Vue change military time into standard time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, time

I am fetching arrivalTime from `todos.items`. While fetching the arrivalTime it sorts out military time using `sortedArray function()`. Is there a way to change sorted time values from military to standard after being sorted out?

**View**

```
<div id="app">

  <div v-for="todo in sortedArray">
    {{todo.items.arrivalTime}}
  </div>
   <!-- is there a way to convert to todo.items.arrivalTime as paragraph<p> below -->
  <br>
  <h1>
    <b>Convert Into</b>
  </h1>
  <br>
  <p>09:00 AM</p>
  <p>10:00 AM</p>
  <p>11:00 AM</p>
  <p>02:00 PM</p>
  <p>10:00 PM</p>

</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { id: "1", items:{arrivalTime: "1100"} },
      { id: "2", items:{arrivalTime: "1000"} },
      { id: "3", items:{arrivalTime: "1400"} },
      { id: "4", items:{arrivalTime: "0900"} },
      { id: "5", items:{arrivalTime: "2200"} },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  },
  computed:{
    sortedArray: function() {
      console.log("inside sortedArray");
      function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.items.arrivalTime < b.items.arrivalTime)
          return -1;
        if (a.items.arrivalTime > b.items.arrivalTime)
          return 1;
        return -1;
          }
      return this.todos.sort(compare);
    }
  }
})
```

I tried to use `jsFiddle` and make some change military time into standard time, but it did not work. Below is my code uploaded on `JsFiddle`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/m2sowbv9/19/

Comment: What is standard time for you? I ask because the most standard time in the world is 10:00, 22:00 ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a very similar solution to above. They were faster.

https://jsfiddle.net/goofballtech/gom4rvst/31/

```
fromMilTime: function(time){
      if(parseInt(time) <= 1259){
       return `${time.slice(0,2).padStart(2, '0')}:${time.slice(2).padStart(2, '0')} AM`
      }else if (parseInt(time) >= 1300 && parseInt(time) <= 2359){
        let math = parseInt(time) - 1200
        let temp = math.toString()
        return `${temp.slice(0,1).padStart(2, '0')}:${temp.slice(2,3).padStart(2, '0')} PM`
      }
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to use that function after sortedArray function. As I need to sort the time which was already done. But when I use fromMilTime it converts the time but does not sort time by sortArray function. Any comment on that ?

Comment: what are you wanting to sort by? This was designed to just do the conversion on the fly and return the modified version as that's all i thought you were looking for.

Comment: nevermind. I didn't even pay attention to your existing sort array before, this is using your computed array.. https://jsfiddle.net/goofballtech/gom4rvst/34/

Comment: just being OCD and using an arrow function for sort... https://jsfiddle.net/goofballtech/gom4rvst/37/

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to Vue, but is about JavaScript in general.

Solution you'd be looking for would be somewhere along spliting the military time string by characters and feeding into a Date object - if you'd want full info.

```
var hrs, min, result, time;

time = '1100';

hrs = time.slice(0, 2);
min = time.slice(2, 4);
console.log(hrs, min);

result = new Date;
result.setHours(hrs);
result.setMinutes(min);
console.log(result);
```

That gives you a complete Date object. From there you can format the time with a library like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/docs/Getting-Started).

Or, if you don't need the functionality where you'd later be adding some time to it, need to know the date etc., you can just skip all of that and manipulate the military time string directly.

```js
var hrs, min, result, time;

time = '1100';

hrs = time.slice(0, 2);
min = time.slice(2, 4);

if (parseInt(time) > 1259) {
  result = `${hrs - 12}:${min} PM`;
} else {
  result = `${hrs}:${min} AM`;
}

console.log(result);
```

Also, please note the above is not necessarily 100% correct. E.g. I'm not sure at the moment is 12:59 supposed to be AM or PM where you are from, but I hope you got the gist of it.

Cheers and good luck